# Pixels seem dead but are actually on

Tags: display, lcd

I noticed on my lcd monitor some pixel that look black, they look like some sort of dead pixels but when i tried to take a macro with my iphone it seems like they are actually on and every subpixel looks turned on, just less bright, how is this called and is it possible to solve? they are just like 4 pixels so i don't think the warranty will be able to get me a new one but this is super annoying

[image: On blue screen]

[image: On white screen]

Comment: From the pictures it doesn't really look all that bad, it might be worth taking a more zoomed out photo that shows the problem in context. Anyway you might still be able to put in a warranty claim. Whilst manufacturers normally claim a few isolated dead pixels are "normal", this tends to be on the condition that they are not grouped together.

Comment: Also it might be worth cleaning the area with a suitable cloth (something like a lens wipe is ideal) to make sure there's not grease or something on the surface